# ArgumentException while disposing custom bitmap plotter

Tags: bitmap, dispose, idisposable, argumentexception

I'm facing problems with a custom written plotter class. 
This class is for drawing on a given PictureBox's Image.

Basic usage is something like this:

```
        double[] signal = StaticSignalGenerator.Sinus(10.0, 0.0, 1000, 5);
        using (Plot plotter = new Plot(pictureBox1, Color.White))
        {
            plotter.Draw(signal, Pens.Black);
        }
```

The constructor uses pictureBox1 as reference and White background color will be made for the image. The drawing is a complex transformation in length and in amplitude, it uses graphics to draw in a using block, than the reference pictureBox image will be updated automatically.

I think somewhere there is the problem, because the class is disposed before the pictureBox image could be refreshed?

```
this.pictureBoxRef.Image = this.drawBitmap;
```

Will be better to use a Clone of the bitmap? (if that would stay in the same scope, it is not gonna help I fear)

If I use this class with using block, when reaching the 
dispose phase I got ArgumentException.
The class implements IDisposable, with the following lines:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.pictureBoxRef != null)
            {
                this.pictureBoxRef.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(PictureBoxRef_MouseMove);
            }
            if (this.drawBitmap != null)
            {
                this.drawBitmap.Dispose();
            }
            if (this.initializedBitmap != null)
            {
                this.initializedBitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Invalid parameter: null, ArgumentException was not handled. 
StackTrace is the following:

> System.Drawing.Image.get_Width() System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
>   System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode
>   mode) System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
>   Int16 layer) System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Any idea how to fix this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well what *exactly* does the ArgumentException say? Please give the full stack trace and message.

Comment: No, edit the *full* exception - everything there is about it - into your question. You should have the full stack trace, and I'd expect there to be a message too.

Comment: Edit this into your *question*, not in comments. Also, it sounds like you haven't removed the PictureBox from its container, which wouldn't be good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell as you've given us very little information, but it looks like it's still trying to *draw* a `PictureBox`. It's not clear whether these have any relation to the values you're disposing, but if the `PictureBox` contains one of the `Bitmap` values you're disposing, that could easily be the problem. You probably want to remove the `PictureBox` from the form first, or maybe set its `Image` property to `null`.

(If you could create a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, it would make it considerably easier to help you...)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I edited the post, hope this helps to understand the problem better. Excuse me for the not good explanation.

Comment: @kurtyka: It's still not clear what you expect to be displayed when you've disposed of the image in picture box...

Comment: So I am asking what is the proper way to got the "desired" working? It is not possible to use picturebox as reference and "refresh" the image from inside the Plot class? Should the drawing returns with a Bitmap and the picturebox image refreshed by outside of the class? You see this is my problem, I want the picturebox image refreshed from inside, but I dont know how to dispose the resources.

Comment: @kurtyka: *What* "desired" working? As I say, you haven't said what you want to be displayed when you dispose of the bitmaps...

Comment: Okay, I dont understand now. So that chunck of memory called bitmap is not copied to the picturebox's image when that image got a value, only references to the class's bitmap? So the class has to be alive while the drawing is finished?

Comment: @kurtyka: Yes, that's how objects work in .NET. The values you copy around are references, unless you explicitly clone an object.

Comment: I messed up really bad. Now its okay I need to refactor some of the parts. Thank you for you help and time!

Comment: @kurtyka: No problem - glad you're on the road to sorting it out :)